# How to calculate the intensity of each RGB color channel of an image as a percentage via Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, colors, rgb

How to calculate the intensity of each RGB color channel of an image as a percentage via Matlab?
The following Matlab code does not work properly:

```
    I = imread('3.png'); % read image 

Ir=I(:,:,1); % read red chanel 
Ig=I(:,:,2); % read green chanel 
Ib=I(:,:,3); % bule chanel

% figure, imshow(I), title('Original image')
% figure, imshow(Ir), title('Red channel')
% figure, imshow(Ig), title('Green channel')
% figure, imshow(Ib), title('Blue channel')

%% read the size of the 
m = size(I,1);
n = size(I,2);


R_total= 0;
G_total= 0;
B_total= 0;

for i = 1:m
             for j = 1:n

               rVal= int64(Ir(i,j));
               gVal= int64(Ig(i,j));
               bVal= int64(Ib(i,j));

               R_total= R_total+rVal;
               G_total= G_total+gVal;
               B_total= B_total+bVal;

             end       
end

disp (R_total)
disp (G_total)
disp (B_total)

%% Calcualte the image total intensity
I_total = R_total + G_total + B_total;
disp( I_total)


%% Calculate the percentage of each Channel

 R_precentag =  R_total / I_total * 100 ;   %% Red Channel Precentage
 G_precentag =  G_total / I_total * 100 ;  %% Green Channel Precentage
 B_precentag =  B_total / I_total * 100 ;
```

I could not see the intensity percentage of each channel R, G, B.

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB conserves the data type after division. Because `rval`, `gval`, and `bval` are saved originally as `int64`, this unit type is propagated into `R_total`, `G_total`, `B_total`, and `I_total`. When you try to divide these values to find the percentages, the division operation is performed first (MATLAB works left to right when operations have equal precedence such as multiplication and division). The result of this division retains the `int64` unit type. Because the individual color channel totals is smaller than the total, the result its a value between zero and one. As an integer cannot save a floating point number, the result is rounded to either zero or one.

In order to correctly divide these numbers to find the percentages, first convert them into the double unit type such as:

```
R_precentag = double(R_total) / double(I_total) * 100;
```

Or alternatively save the `rval`, `bval`, and `gval` variables as double to begin with.

As an aside, your code can be drastically improved by taking advantage of MATLAB's matrix vectorization (the addition of `(:)` at the end of a matrix converts the matrix into a vector by stacking the columns), and built-in functions such as `sum`. As a bonus, `sum` accumulates its result as a double by default, removing the need to manually convert each value.

e.g. your simplified code could look something like:

```
I = imread('3.png'); % read image 

Ir=I(:,:,1); % read red channel 
Ig=I(:,:,2); % read green channel 
Ib=I(:,:,3); % read blue channel

R_total= 0;
G_total= 0;
B_total= 0;

R_total = sum(Ir(:));
G_total = sum(Ig(:));
B_total = sum(Ib(:));

disp (R_total)
disp (G_total)
disp (B_total)

%% Calculate the image total intensity
I_total = R_total + G_total + B_total;
disp( I_total)


%% Calculate the percentage of each Channel
 R_precentag =  R_total / I_total * 100 ;   %% Red Channel Percentage
 G_precentag =  G_total / I_total * 100 ;  %% Green Channel Percentage
 B_precentag =  B_total / I_total * 100 ;
```

Comment: Don't forget to convert to double before doing the sums.

Comment: @gnovice Why would you convert to double first? `sum` has no issues taking integers as input and will by default return a `double`.

Comment: Ahh, I wonder if that is newer behavior for `sum`. I recall having to worry about saturation when working with integers, but I guess that's not the case anymore.